# Word or phrase for "mechanism/ability to pause machine in a certain condition"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Air conditioner (or any cooling machine) has mechanism/ability to pause cooling a room for a while. If this ability doesn't exist, the room will get very cold and could freeze anything in the room.

Is there a word or phrase for this mechanism?

Comment: Such things are typically called *govenors* or *moderators*.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a thermostat?

> thermostat
>
> /ˈθəːməstat/
>
> noun
>
> a device that automatically regulates temperature, or that activates a
>   device when the temperature reaches a certain point.
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=thermostat%20definition)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of one single name for the mechanisms, but things for keeping something constant often use the suffix *-stat*: thermostat, rheostat, haemostat, barostat, photostat.

The broader process or phenomenon is generally called *regulation*, though that can mean not only turning things on or off, but also turning them up and down; and it doesn't have to keep effects (e.g. room temperature) in a steady state, it can also gradually change them in a controlled manner. The word *stabilize* may also be useful to express some aspects of the idea.